# python subprocess.call not showing certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to call tree in python with subprocess.call but instead of returning "│" it only returns "�", this also happens with os.system.
using python 3
windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the horror of working with character sets in Windows.  The application is printing out one of the line-drawing characters.  In the MS-DOS code page, that's probably 0x10.  Depending on how your terminal is set up, that might print as a vertical line, or it might print as something else.  If the app has the option to print out ASCII art ( + - | ), that will be more universal.

Comment: is there an alternative method where I can also set the charset in whitch I want the output to be?

Comment: Well, when you typed `dos tree` into a search engine, and found [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree) for `tree`, what did it tell you about that? How about when you tried `tree /?` at the command line (using the standard DOS syntax for getting help with commands)?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda found out how to fix it, it depends where I run the script from, when I run it from the IDE i get the strange "�" character when I run it from the python console I  get nothing but when I run it from cmd I get the right output.